# SQL Server : insert into from select joining the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have 2 tables: one is called `Intermediary` and the other is `Audit_Log` which is an exact copy of `Intermediary` table with an extra column `MODIFIEDDATE` which I plan to add the current datetime.

I'm using SQL Server, so I get the current date & time using `GETDATE()`.

The question is: how do I insert into the `Audit_Log` table from the `Intermediary` table adding the current datetime?

So far I have tried using

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Log
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Intermediary
    INNER JOIN SELECT GETDATE()
```

and

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Log
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Intermediary, SELECT GETDATE()
```

But none of them have worked yet. Thanks!
Other tips and modifications are welcomed.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data -- or at least the table definitions.

Comment: Note that you *might* be better off simply defining the the column that `GETDATE()` is going into with a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT`, and then omitting it from your `INSERT`. You should *really* be defining both the target column (in the `INSERT INTO`) and the source columns (in the `SELECT`) though, as otherwise a DDL change to either object will break the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to mention column names but generally like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Log (<column names>)
SELECT *, getdate() FROM dbo.Intermediary
```

you can avoid mentioning column names if the order of column matches the order of columns from select